# Unable to trigger issuing_authorization.request webhook via Stripe CLI

Tags: terminal, stripe-payments

I'm running into issues trying to test authorization of virtual cards I'm issuing on my test Stripe account. I've been able to successfully create card holders and virtual cards and am currently trying to write webhooks to handle real-time authorizations.

I find the webhook trigger doesn't let me specify a card-holder or a card to try to authorize and whenever I run the trigger, I get a response like this:

`Setting up fixture for: cardholder Running fixture for: cardholder Setting up fixture for: card Running fixture for: card Trigger failed: Request failed, status=400, body={ "error": { "code": "cardholder_phone_number_required", "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/cardholder-phone-number-required", "message": "You cannot create a card without a`phone_number`on file for cardholder: ich_1L9RhDIK0uyzlLuMaZHgCfzP. Please see https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/3d-secure.", "type": "invalid_request_error" } }`

The step to reproduce this on my end was to simply run the forwarding command and the `issuing_authorization.request` commands as described by the documentation. I ran these two commands on separate terminals:

`stripe listen --forward-to localhost:7787/v1/virtual-cards/stripe/hook`

`stripe trigger issuing_authorization.request`

I'm not sure of what to do, especially since all card-holders I've created thus far have phone numbers and I have no way of specifying a card holder when triggering via the CLI, or editing one on my dashboard.

I'll appreciate any help I can get or any nudge in the right direction for solving this issue. Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Are you sure you're creating a Cardholder object with the `phone_number` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/issuing/cardholders/create#create_issuing_cardholder-phone_number)?

Comment: Yes I am, but in any case, assuming I'm not, I've created a bunch of Cardholder objects. How can I specify which `card_holder_id` should be used to the cli

Comment: Instead of triggering the `issuing_authorization.request` event via the CLI, you'd instead simulate a successful (test) payment with the related card/cardholder. That will subsequently fire the event which your webhook can handle.